# Confuse about flip function

Tags: haskell

```
charIn ::  Char -> String -> Bool
charIn _ []       = False
charIn x (y:ys)   = x==y || charIn x ys

isWord :: String -> Bool
isWord = all $ flip charIn "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

-- isword "abc" (Result True)
-- isWord "ab1" (Result False)
```

I'm confuse about the way flip function works. I know it flips first two arguments but how does it work in the above code? Does it just flip the string argument and *charIn "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"* so that it looks like - all $  charIn "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you see a partial application, you can use *eta (η) expansion* to make things more explicit. The eta rule says that if `f` is any function,

```
f = \x -> f x
```

If you type

```
:t flip charIn "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

at the GHCi prompt, you'll get a result that has an arrow (`->`) in it, meaning it's a function. So

```
flip charIn ['a' .. 'z']
=
\x -> flip charIn ['a' .. 'z'] x
```

Now you can apply `flip` to get

```
=
\x -> charIn x ['a' .. 'z']
```

Which is perhaps more clearly written

```
\x -> x `charIn` ['a' .. 'z']
```

or even, using operator section notation,

```
(`charIn` ['a' .. 'z'])
```

Comment: It's much clearer now. But I do have a question. I put your evaluation of flip in the statement but doesnt work though - all $ charIn x ['a'..'z']. It only work when I change it to - all (charIn x) "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Comment: @user124659, you seem to have missed the `\x ->` right before `charIn x ['a' .. 'z']`.

Comment: Oops I missed that part but still isWord1 x = all $ \x -> charIn x ['a' .. 'z'] gives me "No instance for (Show (t10 Char -> Bool))" error.

Comment: @user124659, you don't need that `x` on the left-hand side. If you need more real-time help, you should check out the #haskell channel on FreeNode.

Answer (score 2):

`flip charIn "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is the same as the lambda `\c -> charIn c "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.

`flip charIn` is partially applied to the string; what remains is a function expecting one argument.

Answer (score 0):

`flip` takes the function you pass as an argument and *gives you back* a function that takes parameters in reversed order, what might be confusing you is the pointfree definition of `isWord` and that you partially apply the flipped function to one of its arguments.

You start with `charIn` and flip its arguments so now it is `String -> Char -> Bool`, then you apply it to `String` argument `"abc..."` and get back `Char -> Bool`. Then you do one more partial application: `all` takes a function from elements to `Bool` and a list of elements, which `Char -> Bool` and `String` aka `[Char]` are. So from `(Char -> Bool) -> String -> Bool`, which is the type of `all` in this context, you get the result `String -> Bool` by passing in the first of the arguments.

Also you may want to consider `['a'..'z']` instead of the `"abc...z"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function f with two arguments x and y in that order, i.e. `f x y`.  If you need to fix y and make x as a free variable you can use flip to write it as `flip f y x` and convert to partially applied form by dropping x `flip f y`.  When applied to x, `f x y` will be evaluated.